# How shodan takes screenshots?

Tags: shodan

How Shodan takes screenshots from some webcam even if this webcam (IP adress) requires login?

And how can I protect this? I can't have some thing on LAN network, because I need to join to it from far away location.

Comment: Have you ever heard of that technology called "VPN"? You shouldn't have a web cam accessible from the internet if you need to use it from far away. You should deploy a VPN.

Answer (score 12):

We do not try to authenticate with webcams at all - not even using default credentials. We are only able to grab an image if the device has no authentication enabled and is public on the Internet.

Source: I wrote the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you've read about using Shodan to find and view people's webcams / IP cameras they are probably talking about people who have left the default username and password on their camera's web interface, which is very common - common enough that there are a lot of them on the internet.

The below article gives an overview of the default usernames and passwords - changing these (or just the password) is the first and most important step towards ensuring someone can't randomly view your webcam.  Also make sure that authentication is turned on, if it can be switched on or off.

I don't know if this is the best article and video about it but it does seem to explain how it works.

https://pentesttools.net/how-to-find-vulnerable-webcams-across-the-globe-using-shodan-and-google-kali-linux-2018-1/